# Algorithm to decompose Polygons into lineStrings (Headlands from Plots)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, polygon, turfjs

Consider the following polygon (an agricultural plot)
[image: An agricultural plot]

From this polygon, I would like to extract the "headlands" of the plot, being the consecutive lines (sides) of the polygon ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headland_(agriculture))) used for turning on the field. While often only the rows running perpendicular to the lay of the field are considered, I need all sides of the polygon.

Here, a consecutive line means any set of coordinates, where the angle between any two coordinates of the set is not larger than a value X (e.g 30 degrees).
For the given example, the resulting headlands should look like the following:

[image: Headlands in example]

I wrote a small algorithm trying to accomplish this, basically checking the angle between two coordinates and either pushing the given coordinate to the existing lineString if the angle is below X degrees or creating a new lineString (headland) if not. 
[Check out the following Gist](https://gist.github.com/chrispahm/8fcdd7a20ab03d226c9e4e5f60b8d68e)

However, in some cases corners of a field are rounded, therefore may consist of many coordinates within small distances of each other. The relative angles then may be less than the value X, even though the corner is too sharp to actually be cultivated without turning.
In order to overcome that issue, I added an index that increases whenever a coordinate is too close for comparison, so that the next coordinate will be checked against the initial coordinate. [Check out the following Gist](https://gist.github.com/chrispahm/3b856016004a330d94f6f4191b47691e).

This works for simple plots like the one in the example, however I am struggling with more complex ones as the following. [image: Second example plot]

Here, the bottom headland is recognised as one lineString together with the headland on the right, even though optically a sharp corner is given. Also, two coordinates in the upper right corner were found to be a separate headland even though they should be connected to the right headland. The result should therefore yield in the following:[image]

What I would like to know is if there is an approach that efficiently decomposes any polygon into it's headlands, given a specific turning angle. I set up a repo for the code [here](https://github.com/chrispahm/vorgewende), and an online testing page with many examples [here](https://chrispahm.github.io/vorgewende/) if that helps.

Comment: To begin with, have a look at this Wikipedia entry (don't miss the section 5). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've been fiddling around with the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm, it turns out it is implemented in the `turf.simplify` function if I understand correctly. It seems like simplifying the polygons before running the algorithm increases the quality, however finding an adequate tolerance measure seems to be rather difficult, and often still results in finding the "wrong" headlands". I created another Gist which you can copy into the dev Console when checking an example on the page [here](https://gist.github.com/chrispahm/fca0da210726aa10b075c1e75a2c8367)

Comment: "simplifying the polygons before running the algorithm": but this *is* the simplification algorithm !?

Comment: That's right, but as it is "solely" simplifying the polygon I have to do the cutting into lineStrings myself, as I require the headlands as single lineStrings